# Vendor(s) for machines supporting ppc64el

Tags: hardware, powerpc

When I look at `rmadison`, I see that on occasion a package is built for the ppc64el platform.

A minimum working example of such would be:

```
 $ rmadison qtel
 qtel | 14.08.1-2 | xenial/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 qtel | 17.12.1-2 | bionic/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 qtel | 17.12.2-1 | cosmic/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 qtel | 17.12.2-4 | disco/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 qtel | 17.12.2-4 | eoan/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
```

When I visit `cdimages.ubuntu.com` I find [install media available](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/) for ppc64el as an ISO image.

From what vendor can an end-user currently purchase hardware on the ppc64el platform?

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  Hardware and shopping recommendations are in the topics to avoid section of https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Considering that Planet Ubuntu is starting to talk about esoteric platforms we build software for such as [ppas for s390x *mainframe* installations](https://princessleia.com/journal/2019/06/building-a-ppa-for-s390x/) my judgment is that it is worth it in this case.  No specific hardware is recommended.  A research path is given since *all* the vendors appear to be located under this single umbrella foundation.  The last time I've seen any other mentions of this are [now found in archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170624133750/http://randall.executiv.es/openpower-developer-challenge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenPOWER Foundation backs the current generation of PowerPC hardware.  Their [resource catalog](https://openpowerfoundation.org/technical/resource-catalog/) lists available systems that can be purchased among other equipment.